# Unable to get the transactions of specific subscription

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am creating subscription from **Axios** in node js and after the user clicks the service, and i get the subscription id on success callback, i am unable to retrieve the last payment transaction that was executed in the current subscription

All i am getting is empty JSON object `{}`

PS: The URL i am using is `/v1/billing/subscriptions/{id}/transactions`

The image for the same with some URLs

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transactions of subscription won't be retrieved instantly. It requires some time, about 5 - 10 mins. The paypal needs some time to verify the transactions and then transfer funds.